# Gridview items changes order using a RecyclerView

Tags: android, gridview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

The gridview items change order randomly sometimes when i click on items and mostly when scrolling. I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find a solution which works for recyclerview.

This is my layout adapter class

```
public class LayoutAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LayoutAdapter.SimpleViewHolder>{
    private static final int COUNT = 100;
    private static final String TAG = "LayoutAdapter";
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TwoWayView mRecyclerView;
    private final int mLayoutId;
    private int mCurrentItemId = 0;
    private FileManager file_manager;
    private ArrayList<Integer> positions;
    private static LayoutInflater inflator = null;
    private TextView folder_name;
    private Context c;
    ArrayList<String> mDataSource, mMultiSelectData;
    private File file, files;
    private File[] list2;
    public boolean multi_select_flag = false;

    public class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public SimpleViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFolderThumbnail);
            folder_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFolderTitle);
        }
    }


    //In logcat I see this constructor is being called again and again and again!

    public LayoutAdapter(Context context, TwoWayView recyclerView, int layoutId, FileManager filemanager, String file_path) {
        mContext = context;
        file_manager = filemanager;
        c = context;
        mDataSource = new ArrayList<String>(file_manager.setHomeDir
                (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()));

        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mLayoutId = layoutId;
        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        if (file_path == null) {
            file = new File(root_sd);
        } else {
            file = new File(root_sd + "/" + file_path);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "GOT ALL FILES >>>>>>" + root_sd);
        list2 = file.listFiles();
    }





    public String getName(int position) {
        String name = list2[position].getName();
        return name;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    public String getData(int position) {

        if (position > mDataSource.size() - 1 || position < 0)
            return null;

        return mDataSource.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //        boolean isVertical = (mRecyclerView.getOrientation() ==TwoWayLayoutManager.Orientation.VERTICAL);
        final View itemView = holder.itemView;
        int num_items = 0;
        String temp = file_manager.getCurrentDir();
        File file = new File(temp + "/" + mDataSource.get(position));
        String[] list = file.list();

        if (list != null)
            num_items = list.length;

        Log.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>>> " + String.valueOf(file.length()));
        folder_name.setText(file.getName());
     }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSource.size();
    }

}
```

This is the layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="105dp"
android:layout_height="105dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.filemanager.android.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFolderThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFolderTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivFolderThumbnail"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivMultiSelect"
    android:layout_width="50dp "
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tvFolderTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivFolderThumbnail"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: folder_name and thumbnail shoukd be fields of your custom ViewHolder

Comment: sorry @pskink i can't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please clarify a little?  those fields should be in onBindViewHolder or SimpleViewHolder?

Comment: they should be declared inside SimpleViewHolder

Comment: You are using TwoWayView, so I would suggest creating an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/

Similar case happens with framework's StaggeredGridLayoutManager which is due to ImageViews resizing when Images are loaded. You need to avoid it as item resize will invalidate position calculations.

If it is a simple grid, try w/ framework's implementation of GridLayoutManager.

Comment: If your problem not solved yet,,,check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29137921/1881611

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post the layout definitions as well? We already know that if the items do not have fixed or pre-defined dimensions, then the items may shift order in case of TwoWay/Recycler Views.

This happens because in recycler view older item views are reused when we scroll down and older item dimensions may differ from the new item dimensions. Hence they may reorder.

In that case setting fixed dimensions for your ImageView and TextView would solve the issue or determine the dimension of the ImageView before inflating.

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem. I'm really annoyed with it.

Comment: I have added the layout file

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the same problem, which is/was really annoying. I tested several things and one of them did the trick: I dont know why but you have to set the item animator explicitly to null for the recycler view with `[RecyclerView].setItemAnimator(null)`; ... Especially the first items reordered when scrolling up again in my staggered layout. Now it is gone. Hope this helps you as well.

[Issue @ GitHub](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/issues/190)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very annoying; the solution which I have realized is in adapter just clear all the conditions like for every if condition there will also be else with valid body.
Try this approach you will get rid of this issue.