# TwoWay View Add empty space automatically

Tags: android, padding, android-library

Two way View is a powerful library to customize grid of components a using `RecyclerView`

Below is the screenshot of problem that we are facing while using this library,so i find out the resolution of that problem,

[image]

[Reference Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28431527/1881611)

[Padding problem #140](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/issues/140)

[Items changing height results in empty space #156](http://Items%20changing%20height%20results%20in%20empty%20space%20#156)

Other questions related to this issue could be

**Q:1 - Gridview items changing order upon scrolling**

**Q:2 -UI mess while loading image with UniversalImageLoader**

Comment: It looks like you're self-answering, but it's really difficult to determine what's actually being asked here. Can you move the actual question being asked into the question itself? I'm happy to reopen this if you do.

Comment: If you are familiar with TwoWay-View Library , then this question is not difficult to understand, if you don't then this is not for you,,

Comment: That one sentence is all the context this needed. Thanks for doing that, and sorry for the bother :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After searching a couple of months ,I found one solution for above issues.

I am going to explain step by step

**First of all keep you must use code of [TwoWay-View](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) library not jar.**

> 1. Open **layout** folder of library.
> 2. Browse the package `org.lucasr.twowayview.widget`
> 3. Open `BaseLayoutManager` `class`
> 4. Jump to ***`Line no. 362`***
> 5. You will found code as
>
>    `if (anchorItemPosition > 0 && (refreshingLanes || !restoringLanes))
>      {`
>
>    replace this line by this one
>
>    ```
>    if (anchorItemPosition > 0 && refreshingLanes && !restoringLanes) {
>    ```

Above change in `BaseLayoutManager class` work for me as a solution to above mentioned issues.

Hope this will help you all **TwoWay-View** users.

Comment: Great answer, it's help me a lot, but I still have that issue and one more http://pastebin.com/3StXhzBA if I try set itemView height from loaded image height http://pastebin.com/L7EQdHFy

Comment: I think this issue related to https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/pull/214 check this if solved let me know please, if not then we together try to resolve it :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help me  :(, can you write me on email davyjonesua@gmail.com or skype: davyjonesua I hope for you.

Comment: Check this changes 
https://github.com/md5555/twoway-view/commit/530cc45bf9bb80754866d05e163b2736bfa0f07e

If your ItemEntries is same as right side then change it to left one.Otherwise i will send you my updated TwoWay-View code to your email, just try above solution first.

Comment: Yes I change all my code from this pull https://github.com/md5555/twoway-view/blob/0edf3273c253cb05fc5f8b47702041b828669645/layouts/src/main/java/org/lucasr/twowayview/widget/ItemEntries.java
And it does not work, the same error

Comment: Replace your ItemEntry class with https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/blob/master/layouts/src/main/java/org/lucasr/twowayview/widget/ItemEntries.java it will remove the error, try it

Comment: Do you know if this fix is going to be adopted into the TwoWayView master branch anytime soon?

Comment: It is already there but not merged with master branch, i don't know why :-/

Comment: I did that. Fix the issue... however i get "the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find span for position 5" sometimes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find span for position 12"